# MailChimp Newsletter Signup Conflicting with jQuery Slide

Tags: jquery, conflict, mailchimp

I have a mailchimp newsletter signup box and a jQuery slide that conflict. The slide does not stop working, however the newsletter signup does nothing when the submit button is clicked. It seems the click function has been disabled by the jQuery used for the slide.

**Newsletter Signup Code:**

```
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="http://seasonsfour.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=218dcaf8b440a1bd002f249a0&amp;id=d81a674a64" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div class="mc-field-group">
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email newslettersignupfield" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter your email here...">
    </div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
        <input type="image" src="images/button-newsletter-signup.jpg" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="newslettersignupbutton">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

**Slide Code:** (When I remove the "input" part of this code the email signup works properly, but the prev/next buttons on the slide stop working.)

```
    var api;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
api =  jQuery('.banner-simple').revolution(
    {
        delay:5000,
        startheight:388,
        startwidth:1000,

        hideThumbs:200,

        thumbWidth:100,                         // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
        thumbHeight:50,
        thumbAmount:5,

        navigationType:"none",              // bullet, thumb, none
        navigationArrows:"none",                // nexttobullets, solo (old name verticalcentered), none

        navigationStyle:"custom",               // round,square,navbar,round-old,square-old,navbar-old, or any from the list in the docu (choose between 50+ different item), custom

        navigationHAlign:"center",              // Vertical Align top,center,bottom
        navigationVAlign:"bottom",                  // Horizontal Align left,center,right
        navigationHOffset:0,
        navigationVOffset:20,

        soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
        soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
        soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
        soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

        soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
        soloArrowRightValign:"center",
        soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
        soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

        touchenabled:"on",                      // Enable Swipe Function : on/off
        onHoverStop:"on",                       // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off

        stopAtSlide:-1,
        stopAfterLoops:-1,

        shadow:1,                               //0 = no Shadow, 1,2,3 = 3 Different Art of Shadows  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)
        fullWidth:"off"                         // Turns On or Off the Fullwidth Image Centering in FullWidth Modus
    });
});



var tpj=jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function() {

// listen for slide change event

api.bind("revolution.slide.onpause",function (e,data) {
    jQuery('#callbackinfo').html('Last Event: Timer Pause ');
});

api.bind("revolution.slide.onresume",function (e,data) {
    jQuery('#callbackinfo').html('Last Event: Timer Resume ');
});

// bind to button click
jQuery("input").click(apiHandler)

function apiHandler(e) {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
        case "pause":
            api.revpause();
        break;
        case "resume":
            api.revresume()
        break;
        case "prev":
            api.revprev()
        break;
        case "next":
            api.revnext()
        break;

    }
    return false;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be more specific when calling the `jQuery("input").click(apiHandler)`. If you have some container ID, then use that before input:

```
jQuery("#id_container input").click(apiHandler)
```

That way, inputs inside the MailChimp code won't be affected.